# Scraping glovo product and price

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I should do some web scraping of multiple glovo sites, the information I need to extract is the header of the various products and the price. I have tried using the BeautifulSoup library, but the information I need to extract is quite nested. I set up the code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def filter_price(price):
    if price[0] == '€':
        return price[1:]
    else:
        return price[0:len(price)-1]
    return

df_siti_1 = pd.read_excel(".../Link glovo KFC.xlsx", header=None)
siti_1=df_siti_1[0].tolist()


#Automatic code for gathering the lenghts
len_menus = []
siti_1_filtered = []
iterator=0
for url in siti_1:
    iterator+=1
    print(f"I am at:{100*iterator/len(siti_1)}%", end="\r")
    result = requests.get(url)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")
    menus = doc.findAll("div", class_="product-row") #HERE THE PROBLEM
    if len(menus) > 0:
        ##save length and corresponding URL, drop the others
        len_menus.append(len(menus))
        siti_1_filtered.append(url)


tuples = [(idx, i) for d, idx in zip(len_menus, siti_1_filtered) for i in range(1, d+1)]
multi_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["URL", "nid"])
##Initialize the dataframe
df_new_1 = pd.DataFrame(index=multi_idx, columns=["name", "price"])


for url in siti_1_filtered:
    print(url, end="\r")
    #print(result)
    result = requests.get(url)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")

    menus = doc.findAll("div", class_="product-row")
    db_name=[]
    db_price=[]
    for menu in menus:
        name = menu.find("p", class_="product-row__name")   #HERE THE PROBLEM
        price = menu.find("span", class_="product-price__effective product-price__effective--new-card") #HERE THE PROBLEM
    #print(name.text + " > " + price.text)
        db_name.append(name.text)
        db_price.append(price.text)
    #df_new.loc[url, 'name'] = pd.Series(db_name)
    #df_new.loc[url, 'price'] = pd.Series(db_price)
    ## Once you filter, no problem
    price_float = []
    for pr in db_price:
        price_float.append(filter_price(pr))

    df_new_1.loc[url, 'name'] = db_name
    #df_new.loc[url, 'price'] = db_price
    df_new_1.loc[url, 'price'] = price_float


#the code continues...
```

Basically, I cannot find the correct html code, am I doing something wrong due to the fact that the code presents a '<span

I am inserting here a link where I can do some testing:
https://glovoapp.com/it/it/leini-settimo-torinese/kfc-lst/

The end result should be a database with title and price information, for example:
Box Meal Colonel's Burger -> 15,50
Menu Colonel's Burger -> 11,90 €

From here I can't go any further, I hope I was clear with respect to what I need to do, in case anyone can solve the problem I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://glovoapp.com/it/it/leini-settimo-torinese/kfc-lst/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = []
for p in soup.select('[type="product_row"]'):
    name, desc, price = p.get_text(strip=True, separator="|||").split("|||")
    data.append((name, desc, price))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Description", "Price"]).drop_duplicates()
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

| Name | Description | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Box Meal Colonel's Burger | Il Box Meal contiene un Colonel's Burger (bacon, formaggio, insalata, salsa barbecue, maionese e un irresistibile filetto Original Recipe), una porzione di Pop Corn Chicken, un contorno speciale, patatine e bibita a scelta. Così buono che il Colonnel... | 15,50 € |
| Menu Colonel's Burger | Menu con un contorno a scelta, una bibita e il Burger del Colonnello. Bacon, formaggio, insalata, salsa barbecue, maionese e un irresistibile filetto Original Recipe, preparato secondo la sua leggendaria ricetta, con il mix segreto di 11 erbe e spezie. | 11,90 € |
| Menu Double Krunch | Menu con un contorno a scelta, una bibita e il Double Krunch, che raddoppia la sua croccantezza con 2 Tenders Crispy! | 10,90 € |
| Box Meal Zinger | Box con Zinger (burger dal delizioso filetto di pollo con panatura Hot & Spicy, lattuga, cheddar e doppio strato di maionese), 2 Hot Wings, patatine, bibita e una pannocchia . Only the brave! | 14,90 € |
| Box Meal All Star | Box con Double Krunch, un Tender Crispy, pannocchia, patatine e bibita a scelta. | 14,50 € |

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your reply, the code works until I come across sites that apparently look the same but evidently have a different html code, for example this one: 
https://glovoapp.com/it/it/catania/kfc-cat

gives me this error:
not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

how can I merge the codes to have a complete exhaust without interruptions due to different HTML?
Thanks already in advance for any reply

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information and the attached link. The issue is at this line.

```
name = menu.find("p", class_="product-row__name")
```

this class has a `div` tag on the attached link, not a `p` tag.

So changing this line to the following should work.

```
name = menu.find("div", class_="product-row__name")
```